# Create Excel file from ReportViewer and SQL Server Report

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc-3, report-viewer2010

I have a web application that has a grid displaying a paged list of data to the user.  The user needs the option to download the results to an Excel spreadsheet. However, the items displayed in the grid are, like I said, Paged and I need the whole result set.  In addition, I'm only displaying about 7 fields per item, whereas the spreadsheet will contain all 20+ fields for an item. So, I'm not looking for a grid-to-Excel solution.

I'm trying to do something that I've actually worked with before. At a previous employer (source code not available), we had an application that contained SQL Server report as an RDLC file.  We would create a ReportViewer control in code (var reportViewer = new ReportViewer()).  Then, we would bind the report to the control, give it a datasource and then render the results in whatever format we needed. In my case I need an Excel File, and then stream the ExcelFile back to the user in the response.

I'm using MVC3, so I'll be returning the Excel file as a FileContentResult.  I've been searching the internet for a day and can't quite find what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller action. The format parameter should be 'EXCEL'.

```
    public FileResult Report(String format)
    {
        LocalReport report = new LocalReport();
        report.ReportPath = Server.MapPath("~/TestReport.rdlc");

        report.DataSources.Clear();
        report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(GetData()));

        report.Refresh();

        return GetFileContentResult(report, format, null, "TestReport");
    }
```

Helper method that creates a FileContentResult from any Report.

```
    public FileContentResult GetFileContentResult(Report report, String format, String deviceInfo, String fileDownloadName)
    {
        String mimeType;
        String encoding;
        String filenameExtension;
        String[] streamIds;
        Warning[] warnings;

        FileContentResult fileContentResult = new FileContentResult(report.Render(format, deviceInfo, out mimeType, out encoding, out filenameExtension, out streamIds, out warnings), mimeType);
        fileContentResult.FileDownloadName = Path.ChangeExtension(fileDownloadName, filenameExtension);

        return fileContentResult;
    }
```

Edit: Forget to call the help function. Oops.

Answer (score 0):

You might try something like the following... We fill a list of objects from our data access level and then pass that list of objects to something like the following...

```
public static byte[] SaveExcelData<T>(List<T> answer)
{
    byte[] fileData = null;

    var grid = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView();

    grid.DataSource = answer;
    grid.DataBind(); 

    HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
    string headerAddition = "attachment; filename=";
    headerAddition += answer[0].GetType().Name + ".xls";
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", headerAddition);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/excel";
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    grid.RenderControl(htw);

    fileData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sw.ToString());

    return fileData;
}
```

Comment: I had tried something like this earlier (although I didn't use a gridview). While it worked, it prompted the user before opening the file, saying the Excel workbook wasn't in the correct format.